# Python print to the end of the window

Tags: python, printing, styles, pretty-print, user-friendly

Trying to figure out how to stylistically print "Done." at the end of the window.

I am printing dynamically using flush. A snippet of code would be:

```
print("Opening the file "),
sys.stdout.flush()
for i in range(3):
    print("."),
    sys.stdout.flush()
print("\tDone.")
```

Except I would like "Done." to be printed all the way at the end of the line no matter how big the window is.

Answer (score 0):

This finds the length of the console window, then makes a string of spaces, with `Done.` at the end.

```
import os
rows, columns = os.popen('stty size', 'r').read().split()
spaces = ''.join([' '] * (int(columns) - 5))
done = spaces + 'Done.'
print(done)
```

Comment: Close but I figured out why it wasn't perfect.
in the section 
    (int(colums) - 5))

it doesnt take into account the size of the initial string or the dots.
so it should be
    (int(colums) - 5 - 17 - 3)